# Should the URL bar be showing in Firefox and iOS installed PWAs?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

My PWA installs fine via Chrome and Edge browsers on Android devices - the PWA opens in standalone mode and does not show the URL bar. Good :-)

The same doesn't happen via Firefox on Android or Safari on iOS. If I hit "Add to Homescreen' in Firefox or the share button > Add to Homescreen > Add via Safari on iPhone, the app's icon is added to the homescreen but when I open it (and no matter how many times I close/open it) the URL bar still displays, and my checks for standalone mode show false.

Is this expected behavior on Android for Firefox installed PWAs and iOS for Safari installed PWAs?

I also noticed that when running the PWA from the homescreen icon on iOS it opens in Safari. Is this normal?

Thank you.